# mediaelement.js IE and Safari issue with WAV files

Tags: safari, internet-explorer-9, mediaelement.js

Trying to make it work mediaelement.js with .wav files on IE and Safari. It's working fine in FF and Chrome. In IE and Safari the player is shown but there is no playback.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer's AUDIO tag doesn't support .WAV; you must use MP3, or, if you have Google's OGG codec installed, OGG.

Comment: I thought there might be any solution. Thanks